# could not import path (Config.Importer not installed)

Tags: go

When I use

```
import (
"go/types"
"go/importer"
)

conf := types.Config{
    Importer: importer.For("source", nil),
}
pkg, err := conf.Check(importSpec.Path.Value, fset, files, nil)
```

This errors on some machines saying

> could not import path (Config.Importer not installed)

(see https://golang.org/src/go/types/resolver.go - line 155)

For my usecase I can't use the importer.Default().
Why is this failing on some machines? What can I do to get the source importer on all machines?

Comment: Did you distribute the source to all your machines? or did you only distribute the binary executable? And if you did distribute the source, is it at the same location on each machine? with the same goenv (GOPATH, etc.)? (Not sure whether that's required but I imagine it would be).

Comment: The errors is happening when running the tests.   
See https://travis-ci.org/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/jobs/412389617  
Running the same on localhost works fine...